# First column's data is missing

Tags: loops, select, abap, opensql

I am a newbie to ABAP. I am trying this program with open sql, and when I execute the program, the first column's data is always missing. I have looked up and the syntax appears to be correct. I am using kna1 table, the query is pretty simple too. If anybody notice the issue, please help me out.

```
DATA: WA_TAB_KNA1 TYPE KNA1,
      IT_TAB_KNA1 TYPE TABLE OF KNA1,
      V_KUNNR TYPE KUNNR.

SELECT-OPTIONS: P_KUNNR FOR V_KUNNR.

SELECT name1 kunnr name2
       INTO TABLE IT_TAB_KNA1 FROM KNA1
       WHERE KUNNR IN P_KUNNR.

LOOP AT IT_TAB_KNA1 INTO WA_TAB_KNA1.
  WRITE:/ WA_TAB_KNA1-KUNNR,' ', WA_TAB_KNA1-NAME1.
ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic - I suppose every ABAP developer has to experience this at least once.

You're using an internal table of structure `KNA1`, which means that your target variable has the following structure

```
 ccckkkkkkkkkklllnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN...
```

with `ccc` being the client, `kkkkkkkkkk` being the field `KUNNR` (10 characters), `lll` the field `LAND1` (3 characters), then 35 `n`s for the field `NAME1`, 35 `N`s for the field `NAME2` and so on.

In your `SELECT` statement, you tell the system to retrieve the columns `NAME1`, `KUNNR` and `NAME2` - **in that order!** This will yield a result set that has the following structure, using the nomenclature above:

```
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnkkkkkkkkkkNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Instead of raising some kind of type error, the system will then try to squeeze the data into the target structure - mainly for historical reasons. Because the first fields are all character fields, it will succeed. The result: the field `MANDT` of your internal table contains the first three characters of `NAME1`, the field `KUNNR` contains the characters 4-13 of the source field `NAME1` and so on.

Fortunately the solution is easy: use `INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE` instead of `INTO TABLE`. This will cause the system to use a fieldname-based mapping when filling the target table. As tomdemuyt mentioned it's also possible to roll your own target structure -- and for large data sets, that's a really good idea because you're wasting a lot of memory otherwise. Still, sometimes this is not an option, so you really have to know this error - recognize it as soon as you see it and know what to do.

Comment: Greetings, you might also want to mention the other ( more elegant ) solution of building a type for the internal table which contains only the selected columns.